# Swapping names using indexOf and substring and compareTo

Tags: java, string, swap

I am having trouble understanding how to use the `indexOf()` and `substring()` and `compareTo()` methods to flip people's first name with their last name in an array.

Comment: Can you post the complete description of the problem you are trying to solve? indexOf, substring and compareTo aren't really used to change things in an array, it sounds like there's some larger problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem a little?  What values are in this array?

Comment: Well it is a program for a class that I am haveing trouble with. i have a names array with first and last names in it and our professor was trying to explain to us how to use indexof to find the space inbetween the names and substring with something and the compaeto also im not sure how it fits together

Comment: For example
String[] names={"Mary Smith","John Cummings","Herald Williams","Debbie Boile","Ralph Chester"};
i need to switch the last name with there first names so i can sort by last names later on

Comment: Title and text edited for readability; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: If you're serious about learning, try http://codingbat.com/java ; it has hundreds of exercises for beginners, including sections on basic `String` manipulations

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following:

```
String[] names = new String[]{"Joe Bloggs", "Sam Sunday"};
```

You can use the following code to swap the last name and first name:

```
for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    String someName = names[i];
    int spaceBetweenFirstAndLastName = someName.indexOf(" ");
    //These next two lines of code may be off by a character
    //Grab the characters starting at position 0 in the String up to but not including
    //   the index of the space between first and last name
    String firstName = someName.substring(0, spaceBetweenFirstAndLastName);
    //Grab all the characters, but start at the character after the space and go 
    //   until the end of the string
    String lastName = someName.substring(spaceBetweenFirstAndLastName+1);
    //Now, swap the first and last name and put it back into the array
    names[i] = lastName + ", " + firstName;
}
```

The string `compareTo` method can now be used to sort the names by comparing one name against another, now that the last name is the start of the string.  Have a look at the api [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and see if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use the split method to separate the names into a String array, considering that they are separed by a space.

For example, lets consider a name:

```
String name = "Mario Freitas";

String[] array = name.split(" "); // the parameter is the string separator. In this case, is the space

for(String s : array){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

this code will print each name in a different line (as the String was separated)

Then you can compare the first and last name separated, using the equals method.

Let's suppose you have 2 array of Strings, obtained by split method and each one with one different Person name.

```
public void compare names(String name1, String name2){
    String array1[] = name1.split(" ");
    String array2[] = name2.split(" ");

    if(array1[0].equals(array2[0])){
        System.out.println("First names are equal");
    }

    if(array1[1].equals(array2[1])){
        System.out.println("Second names are equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: all the names are already stored in a string array i need to flip them and put them back in the same array

Comment: You can flip the names using the split method. Just create another string filling it with the values of the array fliped. Then you have the fliped name. Ex.: String s = array1[1] + " " + array1[0];

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, specifically [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to reorder the first name and last name.

```
    String[] names = { "John A. Doe", "James Bond" };
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i] = names[i].replaceAll("(.*) (.*)", "$2, $1");
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    }
```

This prints:

```
Doe, John A.
Bond, James
```

However, if the only reason why you're swapping is because you later want to sort on last names, then you actually don't need to swap at all. Just encapsulate the last name extracting code into a helper method (so it's testable, reusable, etc), and then use it in your custom [`java.util.Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for [`java.util.Arrays.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

```
import java.util.*;

//...

static String lastName(String name) {
    return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(' '));
}

//...

String[] names = { "John A. Doe", "James Bond" };       
Comparator<String> lastNameComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override public int compare(String name1, String name2) {
        return lastName(name1).compareTo(lastName(name2));
    }           
};
Arrays.sort(names, lastNameComparator);
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

This prints:

```
James Bond
John A. Doe
```

Note that in both snippets, it's the *last* index of the space character that is used to define the boundary between the first and last name.